# Minimal installation of Latex with Tikz for a web server

Tags: installing

What can you recommend for installing bare minimum in order to compile latex files on the fly in a web server running on Windows 2003 server in a VM? **The only 2 required packages will be Geometry and Tikz**. Potentially there could be other packages used, but not immediately.

There is only 2 GB free space and keeping this to a bare minimum is a requirement. Ideally installation should reside in the VM for it to be self-contained and snapshottable.

I am only experienced with doing full installs of texlive. What other methods of installing Latex on Windows would be suitable for the above scenario?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? The easiest way to enable LaTeX in web pages is using MathJax. It doesn't require any installation just an extra line in your html source code.

Comment: We need to call PDFLaTeX from web server program code. We do not use JavaScript.

Answer (score 1):

MikTex sounds like a solution as it installs bare minimum and downloads required packages the 1st time source is compiled. MikTex installation that downloaded PGF, Forest, PST-Barcode and a few other packages is about 400 MB while a full TexLive installation would be 2+ GB.